# Custom fonts disappear when I use custom screen sizes in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I'm trying to define different font sizes for different screen types from IB. But when I do it, custom fonts disappear.

EDIT: I recorded [this screen capture](http://youtu.be/mHqqluZH92k) will explain the problem better.

**Before:**

[image: Attributes before the changes]
[image: Screenshot before the changes]

**After:**

[image: Attributes after the changes]
[image: Screenshot after the changes]

So, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To see your `UIButton` at the style you specified, pick the proper size at the bottom of **IB**.

Comment: I'm trying to define different font sizes for buttons and labels for different screen sizes. To do it from IB, I click "**+**" button next to "**Font**" from properties panel and choose "**compact width & compact height**". Look at the 3rd screenshot please. This is the only change I make and before I do this, custom fonts are working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I don't think you understand the problem. These screenshots are from simulator. When I make that little change, custom fonts are going. This is the problem. Everything is fine on the preview.

Comment: Please watch https://youtu.be/mHqqluZH92k

Comment: You may want to move that video to the question, and remove this comment thread. I can only assume you have verified that the custom font works when outside of size classes. You may also want to check that the **raw** XIB file exhibits proper content, similar to this example: `<variation key="heightClass=regular-widthClass=compact"><fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLight" family="Avenir Next Condensed" pointSize="22"/></variation>`

Comment: I have same problem. Is that a bug from apple side?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is the generic answer to generic fonts and size classes. This answer may not apply to *custom* fonts.

**Interface Builder Preview**

[image: Different fonts in Portrait & Landscape]

---

**Tutorial**

Example to supply different fonts on iPhone Portrait, iPhone Landscape, and everything else. Notice that if you add objects or constraints while in any mode, you will, by default, only apply the change to that size class.

*Assuming you will start with any-any.*

- w**Compact** h**Regular** = all iPhones in Portrait

  step 1:

  Pick the proper set of size classes in the editor.

  [image: Pick wCompact hRegular]

  step 2:

  add a w**C** h**R** to your `UIView`, using **+** in the Attribute Inspector.

  [image: wC hR]
- Repeat with w**Any** h**Compact** = most iPhones in Landscape, add w**Any** h**R**.

  You must repeat step 1. and step 2, first picking the size editor, then hit **+**. When finished, you should have 1 setting per size class:

  [image: Multiple settings]

---

**Build & Run**

[image: Simulator demo]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-33987900) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-33987900).